# Standard way to have a UIBarButtonItem point to the right?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

When a new view controller is pushed onto the navigation stack, there is standard support for a back button with the title of the previous view controller. This button "points" to the left rather than having a rounded rectanglar shape.

Is there a standard way to create a UIBarButtonItem that "points" to the right? This button would be used as the rightBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [Three20 library](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20) you can do it easily without creating an image yourself (and it will size up correctly depending on your text):

[image]

This screenshot comes from the example application that comes with Three20.

Comment: I have been meaning to look through the Three20 library. I will probably grab some other stuff from it too...

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the PNG files floating around with iPhone UI widgets ([example](http://www.google.com/search?q=iphone+ui+widgets)). Take the left-pointing button and flip it horizontally in Photoshop or another image editing tool to make it point right-wards.

Then insert a `UIButton` into the `rightBarButtonItem` view, using the horizontally-flipped widget as its image property.

Comment: By "standard way" I meant not using a custom view. It sounds like the answer to my question is "No, you have to use a custom view." Is that correct?

Comment: Apple does not provide a right-pointing bar button, no. You'll have to use a custom view (which is the "standard way" for dealing with what Apple doesn't provide).